# Creating custom previews for ECL items in the Item View window

Tags: 2013, ecl

My ECL provider points to a system which contains videos, photo galleries and other standard images. When I open an image in the CME it show a clickable image which links to the external asset. I have achieved this by implementing the default `GetThumbnailImage()` and `GetDirectLinkToPublished` methods of the provider.

I would really like to inserts custom HTML code (instead of the standard linked image) in this window, so I can embed functionality for previewing images and galleries. Is this possible through the ECL provider, or do I need to make a GUI extension to add something like a new preview to implement such functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ECL does currently not support this, so you would have to make your own UI extension.